# Does the Shape Water cantrip work on snow or ice?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell description specifically says you can freeze water, but it doesn't mention unfreezing/thawing water that was already frozen or if frozen water counts as water.

Can I use Shape Water to either:

1. Apply any of the standard effects to an equivalent volume of ice without thawing it? or;
2. Thaw an equivalent volume of ice (assuming the effect lasts for an hour then the water freezes again).

This question is specifically about using the spell to effect ice. My party is about to head into snowy mountain region and I want to know if I can use it whilst there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! You can take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more informations about the site. If the Q/A I've linked to above doesn't answer your question, feel free to explain or edit your question further

Comment: *"It can't affect ice or snow, only the colloquial, common, non-chemistry meaning of “water” that means the liquid phase."* from the [accepted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68434/48759) on the duplicate question. Can you clarify how this does not address your question?

Comment: Thanks, some how I read through the answers to that linked question and missed that line. My bad.